# Use supervisor to rerun failing cronjob?

Tags: command-line, cron, supervisor

I want to execute a script every day from 07:00 AM for 17 hours.
I managed to do so by setting up a cronjob that executes every day at 7 AM the following command:

```
/usr/bin/timeout --foreground 17h /home/adam/mycommand
```

Now this works basically, but the problem is that the script sometimes fails. If this happens, I would like to re continue the script for the remaining hours, so that it ends at 00:00 AM

My question is, can I achieve this with supervisor? I followed the [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-manage-supervisor-on-ubuntu-and-debian-vps) but this just shows how to rerun a specific script and restart it when it fails. I don't know how to this in comination with cronjob and timeout

Comment: What do you mean by @supervisor@ there is no such user in Ubuntu.

Comment: It might help to identify the underlying cause of the failure first before searching a solution for an unknown problem

Comment: If you use a systemd timer and service combination you can start the service (your script) at 7am and restart it if it fails. Then you could think about some logic in your script to check the time and end if it’s between midnight and 6.59. It would also be sensible to try to diagnose why it’s failing.